# Data structure to track and store objects when hooking into APIs

Tags: c++, data-structures, dictionary

I am solving a very specific problem which requires using data structures to store and track objects. Using a simple example, say I have the following 2 classes:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo Foo(bool isRed) {m_bRed = isRed} ;
    bool m_bRed;    
}

class Bar
{
    Bar Bar(Foo* pFoo) {m_pFoo = pFoo} ;
    Foo * m_pFoo;    
}
```

As the program runs, many Foos and Bars will be created, and at program termination, I'd like to know how many Bars are red (from it's contained Foo). Please assume there's no getters/setters for both classes, and the only way to solve this problem is to hook into Foo's and Bar's constructors. Now, what's the best data structure to do this?

I think a potential solution is to use two (unordered) maps of the following formats:

```
std::map<Foo*, bool> g_FooContainers;
std::map<Bar*, bool> g_BarContainers;
```

And when Foo is being created, we insert it into its map,

```
g_FooContainers.insert(std::make_pair(Foo*, isRed));
```

And when Bar is being created, we look for the passed-in Foo* in its map, and if found, insert the Bar into its map with the corresponding isRed.

```
r = g_FooContainers.find(Foo*);
if (r != unordered_map::end) 
{
    g_BarContainers.insert(std::make_pair(Bar*, r->second)));
}
```

And at the end of the program execution, we can loop through g_BooContainers and see which Bar is red or not.

Now, I am wondering if there's an more efficient way to do this? Perhaps with only one std::map?

Please let me know.

Comment: Adding getters and setters seems like a much better solution since you've already got a collection. It seems like you are just duplicating the collection to store more data. God help you if they get out of sync.... Another way depending on your needs: just keep one int of the redFooCount and increment on create, decrement on destroy.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest:

1. Keep a set of `Bar*`.
2. Add the `Bar*` to the set in the constructor.
3. Remove the `Bar*` from the set in the destructor.
4. At the end, go through the set of `Bar*` and gather the set of `Foo*` from them. I am assuming `Foo`s are not deleted without deleting the `Bar`s that have a pointer to it. This makes sure that if there are multiple `Bar`s pointing to the same `Foo`, you wouldn't count it more than once.
5. Iterate over the set of `Foo*` and count how many are `red`.

**Sample Code**

```
std::set<Bar*> g_aliveBars;

class Bar
{
   Bar(Foo* pFoo) {m_pFoo = pFoo; g_aliveBars.insert(this);}
   ~Bar() {g_aliveBars.erase(this);}

   Foo * m_pFoo;    
}

int getRedFoos()
{
   std::set<Foo*> aliveFoos;
   for ( auto bar: g_aliveBars )
   {
      aliveFoos.insert(bar->m_pFoo);
   }
   int count = 0;
   for ( auto foo; aliveFoos)
   {
      count += (foo->m_bRed? 1 : 0);
   }
   return count;
}
```

Without getters and setters in classes, I hope you can provide a mechanism to get the `Foo*` from a `Bar`. You can accomplish that by keeping a map of `Boo*` -> `Foo*`. Similarly, you can provide a mechanism to answer whether a `Foo` is red or not. In essence, you would need:

```
std::map<Foo*, bool> g_FooIsRedMap;
std::map<Bar*, Foo*> g_BarToFooMap;
```

Given that, `getRedFoos()` can be translated to:

```
int getRedFoos()
{
   std::set<Foo*> aliveFoos;
   for ( auto bar: g_aliveBars )
   {
      aliveFoos.insert(getFoo(bar));
   }
   int count = 0;
   for ( auto foo; aliveFoos)
   {
      count += (isRed(foo)? 1 : 0);
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: This actually violates the premise that there's no getter/setters for the classes. This is actually not an artificial condition I am imposing. In reality, Foo and Bar are opaque handles to objects, and I have no idea how to retrieve Foo from Bar. And to elaborate more, when I create Foo or Bar, the create functions look more like this "CreateFoo (FooDescriptor desc, Foo** pFoo)" and "CreateBar (BarDescriptor desc, Bar** pBar)"

Comment: @lancery, Granted you don't want getters and setters on the classes. Are you against providing the ability to get the `Foo* from `Bar` by another mechanism and to query whether a `Foo` is red or not? If you are not against that, you can use the core of what I suggested.

Comment: It's not that I am against it, it's just not possible given that constructors of these objects (i.e. CreateFoo and CreateBar) just return opaque object handles so I have no way to get the Foo* from Bar* and query the Foo* for whether it's red or not. That's why I phrased the simplified example this way.

Comment: How were you hoping to get `isRed` and the `Foo*` that you used in your posted code?

Comment: The "IsRed" are passed-in parameters during Foo's constructor, and that's the only place I have access to that information, so that's where Foo* gets added to its map. As for the Foo*, that's likewise a passed-in parameter for Bar's constructor, etc.

Comment: That's precisely the time to update the maps that I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion R Sahu. However, I am not sure I see an obvious benefit of keeping both "std::map<Foo*, bool> and std::map<Bar*, Foo*>" v.s. "std::map<Foo*, bool> and std::map<Bar*, bool>." It looks like the storage and performance requirements between the two approaches wouldn't be much different.